# querydsl default customize method cannot load

Tags: spring, mongodb, querydsl

I add some bindings in customize method, referring to the below code snap. Now there is a strange issue, when restarting the program, the customize method sometimes is loaded, so the method can be called successfully, however sometimes cannot loaded, which leads to wrong query results. I debugged the resource injecting AdminRepository. When unloading customize method, spring's JdkDynamicTarget class has no the method cached:

```
public interface AdminRepository extends CrudRepository<MonthGprs, String>,
    QueryDslPredicateExecutor<MonthGprs>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QMonthGprs> {
Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger (AdminRepository.class);
@Override
default public void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QMonthGprs root) {

    log.debug ("AdminRepository");

    bindings.bind (root.appLeftGprs).all (((path, value) -> {
        Iterator it = value.iterator ( );
        return path.goe ((Float) it.next ( )).and (path.loe ((Float) it.next ( )));
    }));

    bindings.bind (root.wifiLeftGprs).all (((path, value) -> {
        Iterator it = value.iterator ( );
        return path.between ((Float) it.next ( ), (Float) it.next ( ));
    }));

    bindings.bind (root.simInfo.createdDate).all (((path, value) -> {
        Iterator it = value.iterator ( );
        return path.after ((ZonedDateTime) it.next ( )).and (path.before ((ZonedDateTime) it
                .next ( )));
    }));

    bindings.bind (String.class)
            .first ((StringPath path, String value) -> path.containsIgnoreCase (value));
}
```

}
BTW, I use com.querydsl:querydsl-mongodb:jar:4.1.4, org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE,
org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the reason that I defined two repositories for one domain model, however in

```
org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories
```

`private final Map<Class<?>, String> repositoryBeanNames;`

This map maintains a key-value pairs, in which using class as key, repository name as value. If application context has more than one repository for the same domain model, only one repository class is loaded. So if query dsl repository is loaded, the customize method is called, or other repository is loaded.